# Binding events to component's children

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have an ember component with a close button, that will call destroy() on the component. To bind the close button to destroy, for the component I use:

```
 didInsertElement: function () {
        var id = '#' + this.elementId; // this is the component id        
        var close = $(id).find(".close"); // this is the close button
        $(close).on("click", alert('123')); //binding...        
    }
```

Problem is: the alerts do not happen on click, but when the element is inserted: each component element inserted calls 1 alert(123)

Comment: jsbin's are incredibly useful for getting help

Comment: Please do a save-as from your browser to give us some HTML (not page source) to work with :)

Comment: try this $(close).on("click", function() {alert('123');});

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just `this.$('.close').on('click', alert('123'));` since ember already has a reference to the jquery element (`this.$`)